# Java unix filter

Tags: java, unix, filter

How can I write an Java application that will act as a Unix filter

like for example this:

cat file.txt | java process

Comment: You mean `java process < file.txt`, right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `cat file.txt | java process` will work just as well.

Comment: Except it will run an extra executable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read from [`System.in`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in). Write to [`System.out`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out). Do as you like in between.

Answer (score 2):

Read the `stdin`(i.e `System.in`).